# How to make brave browser use computer's proxy settings

Tags: proxy, brave

I've install the Brave browser, but, contrary to Google Chrome and Firefox, it's not working with the proxy configuration and VPN. I tried to go check the settings and search for `proxy`.

From the results I opened `Open your computer's proxy settings` and got the message

> When running Brave under a supported desktop environment, the system
> proxy settings will be used. However, either your system is not
> supported or there was a problem launching your system configuration.
> But you can still configure via the command line. Please see `man brave` for more information on flags and environment variables.

However the `man browser` from terminal is not working.

How can I make Brave browser use my computer's proxy settings?

Answer (score 0):

You should be typing `man brave`, or `man brave-browser`, as is said on the webpage, and not `man browser`. When you do, the man page will tell you to use the command line option --proxy-server when launching brave, which allows you to specify a proxy to use.